# Trait is not implemented for the type `&str` [E0277]

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait definition for str where I define a function taking &self. If I call this function from main on a static &str, all is fine. If I call the same function from a function taking a trait object parameter, I am greeted with the following error: `MyTrait is not implemented for the type`&str`[E0277]`

I have a workaround at the end, but I am not clear on the costs, am I copying the string?

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thingie{
 pub name: String, // rather than &a str for Thingie<'a>
}

trait MyTrait{
    fn to_thingie(&self)->Option<Thingie>;
}

impl MyTrait for str{
    fn to_thingie(&self)->Option<Thingie>{
        println!(">>MyTrait for str");
        Some(Thingie{name:self.to_string()})
    }
}


fn method_on_trait <T:MyTrait> (thing:T){
   let v= thing.to_thingie();
   println!("Method on trait: {:?}",v);
}

fn main(){
 println!("in main: {:?}","test".to_thingie());
 method_on_trait("test");
}

//TODO: Uncomment this for a fix. WHY?
//Is this creating a copy of the string or just transfering the binding?
// impl<'a> MyTrait for &'a str{
//     fn to_thingie(&self)->Option<Thingie>{
//         println!(">>MyTrait<'a> for &'a str");
//         (*self).to_thingie()
//     }
// }
```

Comment: I don't know whether this is good etiquette or not, here is a rust playground link for this code snippet: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=10bd0d565e9106e1900c&version=stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `method_on_trait` that it can work on unsized types and pass it a reference to T (not directly T, which at this point might not be sized and can't be passed by value).
The first you can do adding the `?Sized` "bound" to `T`, the second by making `thing` a `&T`.

```
fn method_on_trait<T: MyTrait + ?Sized> (thing: &T) {
   let v = thing.to_thingie();
   println!("Method on trait: {:?}",v);
}
```

What's going on here, is that `MyTrait` is only implemented for `str`, which is an unsized type. You try passing "test" (which is a `&'static str`) to `method_on_trait` in main, which leads to the `E0277` error.

Your commented code is implementing `MyTrait` for `&str`, which makes your original code compile because you're indeed passing a `&str` to `method_on_trait`. There is no copying of the original string, `&str` is only basically [a pointer to it plus a length info](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/raw.rs.html#62-65).